# Nginx/NChan PubSub - how to modify incoming messages

Tags: nginx, publish-subscribe, nchan

My quest for a simple pubsub server to handle the, relatively modest, publish/subscribe needs for my Android app have lead me to choose [Nchan](https://nchan.io/) - an Nginx extension.  NChan is remarkably flexible and very easy to setup.  For the most part I have been able to work my way through its documentation and understand everything that is required.  However, there is one issue that still eludes me:

One of the capabilities of NChan is to forward incoming messages for upstream processing prior to allowing them to be published and made available to other clients.  The [Message Forwarding](https://nchan.io/#message-forwarding) section of the documentation states

> The upstream response code determines how publishing will proceed:
>   304 Not Modified publishes the message as received, without modification.
>   204 No Content discards the message
>   **200 OK is used for modifying the message. Instead of the original incoming message, the message contained in this HTTP response is published**.

The test stack I have to see how this works is as follows

**My Nginx configuration**

```
location ~ /pub/(\w+)$ 
{
 nchan_publisher;
 nchan_channel_id "$1"; #first capture of the location match
 nchan_publisher_upstream_request /beforepub;
}

location = /beforepub 
{
 proxy_pass https://another-example.com/beforepub/;
 proxy_set_header X-Publisher-Type $nchan_publisher_type;
 proxy_set_header X-Prev-Message-Id $nchan_prev_message_id;
 proxy_set_header X-Channel-Id $nchan_channel_id;
 proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
 proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

I am in essence taking the inbound message and forwarding it to `/beforepub/` on the same server where the following `index.php` script deals with it.

There are one of two things I want to do with this forwarded message

**"Record some information**: in a local database, typically related to the `X-Channel-ID` header and then return a `204` header so that **nothing is published**

```
<?php
 header("HTTP/1.1 204 OK");
 $channelID = getallheaders()['X-Channel-ID'];
 //inspect and record the channel ID
?>
```

**Return a modified response**:

```
<?php
 header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
 $headers = getallheaders();
 $channelID = $headers['X-Channel-ID'];
 //return a response dependendent on the channelID
 echo "modified response";
?>
```

in the hope that what will be seen by other subscribers to the channel will be **modified response**.

To test this behavior in the first instance I am using

- The Chrome [Simple Websocket Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-websocket-client/pfdhoblngboilpfeibdedpjgfnlcodoo?hl=en).
- The chrome [Advanced REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo).

NChan can accept pubsub connections using either the `wss` or `http(s)` protocols.  I am using `wss` for the `sub` connection on Simple Websocket Client, **SWC** and `https` for the pub connection on the Advanced REST client **ARC**.

With this in place I subscribe to messages on the "alpha channel" via **SWC** at

```
wss://example.com:443/sub/alpha
```

and

connect and publish messages on the same "alpha channel" from **ARC** and POST to the url `https://example.com/pub/alpha` with the content POST `original content`.  What I find is that **SWC** is returning an empty response along the lines of

`[2020-01-30 18:04:14.204]`

It is not clear to me whether this is because I have somehow got my Nginx proxy settings wrong or have just completely misunderstood now NChan forwarding is supposed to work.